# Accessing static variables of a model class using reflection

Tags: ios, swift, reflection, mirroring

I have a model class that contains some static variables and properties. In Runtime I can get the properties;

```
let instance = entity.init()

let mirror = Mirror(reflecting:instance)

var propertyStrings = [String]()

for (propertyName, childMirror) in mirror.children {

}
```

But I want to get static variables of the class as a list too. So how can I get the list of static variable's names and values ? Here is my model class' structure :

```
class ActionModel: NSObject {

static let kLastModified = "LastModified"
static let kEntityName = "EntityName"
static let kIdentifier = "Id"


var lastModified: Int64
var entityName: String?
var identifier : PrimaryKeyString
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Getting type properties via reflection is not supported yet. You can see this by inspecting the `displayStyle` of the `Mirror` you get if you pass the class object to the initializer:

```
let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: ActionModel.self)
print(mirror.displayStyle)    // nil
```

Comment: It looks like this is unchanged seven years later?

Answer (score 9):

You might use the Objective-c runtime, especially the function `class_copyPropertyList` which describes the properties declared by a class. Example:

```
import Foundation

class Foo:NSObject {
    @objc static var prop1: String? = "Hello I am prop1!"
    @objc static var prop2: String? = "Hello I am prop2!"
}

var count: CUnsignedInt = 0
let methods = class_copyPropertyList(object_getClass(Foo.self), &count)!
for i in 0 ..< count {
    let selector = property_getName(methods.advanced(by: Int(i)).pointee)
    if let key = String(cString: selector, encoding: .utf8) {
        let res = Foo.value(forKey: key)
        print("name: \(key), value: \(res ?? "")")
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer!. Saved me alot of time