# In Swift, is it possible to get all the **static** properties from a struct?

Tags: swift

I have a struct with a protocol like,

```
protocol Page {
    func getAllProperties () -> [String: Any] 
}

extension Page {
    public func getAllProperties () -> [String: Any] {
        var result: [String: Any] = [:]
        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)
        print(mirror)
        for (labelMaybe, valueMaybe) in mirror.children {
            print(labelMaybe)
            guard let label = labelMaybe else {
                continue
            }

            result[label] = valueMaybe
        }

        return result
    }

}


struct Test: Page {
    static let aa = "aaaaa"
    let bb = "bbbb"
}
```

Here `Test().getAllProperties()` returns only `bb`, it omits the `static` property!!!

I want that `getAllProperties()` return those static property too!

is there any way for it?

Answer (score 6):

To the best of my knowledge, the answer is no. Sorry. Even getting a `Mirror` on the `type(of: self)` doesn't end up having any children.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to turn your struct into a class then that's possible.

You can do this if you'll incorporate some objc during runtime. It doesn't even mean that you need to create objc class, you just need to write some objc c code in your Swift file.

[Please read Andrea Mugnaini answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48906888/4036390)

The idea is to use objc c to read the class properties and present them using Swift.

Notice though, you'll need to mark your class as NSOjbect and your static constants with the prefix "@objc static".

an example:

```
class SomeRandomClass: NSObject {
    @objc public static let my_cool_prop_name = "propValue"
}

static func reflectClass() {
    var count: CUnsignedInt = 0
    let methods = class_copyPropertyList(object_getClass(BtnsBank.self), &count)!
    for i in 0 ..< count {
        let selector = property_getName(methods.advanced(by: Int(i)).pointee)
        if let key = String(cString: selector, encoding: .utf8) {
            print("name: \(key), value: \(res ?? "")")
        }
    }
```

Again, taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48906888/4036390)