# In Swift, how to determine what property called a function? is it possible?

Tags: swift

I have a struct like,

```
struct LoginPage {
    static let usernameField = Element("#username")
}
```

and I have a class like,

```
class LoginView {
  func enterCredentails () {
     LoginPage.usernameField.waitForExist()
  }
}
```

and the `Element` api looks like

```
class Element {
   init(...) {
    ...
   }

   func waitForExist () {
     // print("caller property name")
   }
}
```

...here inside `waitForExist()` I want to get that property name(`usernameField`) who triggered this method. so that I can print the `error` and `success` message dynamically inside `waitForExist()` based on the property name.

is this possible? is there any workaround for this?

NOTE: I have tried using `Mirror` to get all the properties(so that I can store and retrieve the key name based on `Element`), but it is not returning the `static` properties ([Referred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46498219/in-swift-is-it-possible-to-get-all-the-static-properties-from-a-struct)). So I am looking for the alternative solution.

Thanks in advance for helping me out!

Answer (score -1):

I'd recommend the simple approach:

```
func waitForExist(propertyName: String [or possibly make it an enum]) {
    // do what needs to be done
}
```

I'm assuming your properties call this in their `didSet` or something; just have each one pass the appropriate value to the `waitForExist` function.

As for the literal answer to your question, you *could* probably examine the stack using functions like `backtrace()`, but ehhhhhh... trust me, you don't really want to do that.