# Is there a way to reflect an enum with default associated values?

Tags: swift, enums

Effectively, I have an Enum as follows

```
enum Foo {
    case bar(value: String? = nil)
    case baz(value: String? = nil)
}
```

I know that each case is going to have an associated `String?` value with a default of nil.

Now if I want to conform `Foo` to be `CaseIterable`, I need a custom `static var allCases: [Foo]`. Typically this is setup as follows.

```
enum Foo {
    case bar(value: String? = nil)
    case baz(value: String? = nil)

    static var allCases: [Foo] = [bar(), baz()]
}
```

Where I just want to use the default cases in that `allCases` var. However, I'm trying to remove some of the dependency to a protocol because I'm going to have several Enums set up this way. To this end, I've created

```
protocol MyEnums: CaseIterable {
    associatedtype CurrEnum: MyEnum
}

extension MyEnums {
    static var allCases: [CurrEnum] {
        var cases: [CurrEnum] = []
        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)
        mirror.children.forEach { child in
            cases.append(child.value)
        }
        return cases
    }
}
```

And then I setup the Foo enum as

```
enum Foo {
    typealias CurrEnum = Self
    case bar(value: String? = nil)
    case baz(value: String? = nil)
}
```

This doesn't work though, for a couple of reasons I think.

I don't know that child.value is pulling out the correct value, and it's certainly not pulling out the default values. Is there a way to iterate through an enum with associated default values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Mirror` has never worked on metatypes; it's only for instances of types. (E.g. `Mirror(reflecting: Foo.self).children` is empty.)

[Accessing static variables of a model class using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35294323/accessing-static-variables-of-a-model-class-using-reflection)

You can get the associated value of an instance using `Mirror`, but you can't get any information about enum cases. You need to rethink your approach.

If the signatures are the same for every type, you can avoid copy pasta or code generation. Otherwise, you probably cannot.

```swift
protocol Cases: CaseIterable {
  static func bar(value: String?) -> Self
  static func baz(value: String?) -> Self
}

extension Cases {
  static var allCases: [Self] {
    [bar(value: nil), baz(value: nil)]
  }
}

extension Foo: Cases { }
```

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't work if you have associated values.

From the docs https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/caseiterable

> Types that conform to the CaseIterable protocol are typically enumerations without associated values.

This makes sense if you think about it. If you wanted to iterate through every case, if a case had a `String?` associated value then you'd have to be able to iterate over every single possible string or nil :)

Comment: What if I only wanted the current default associated values? Is there no way for me to iterate through an enum and pull each default value then? I was hoping I could do something like iterate through keypaths and initialize them, but I think enum cases are run as functions.